# Concise way to find and remove items from a mutable list

Tags: kotlin

kotlin

I have 2 mutableLists for `new countries` and `current countries`

I want to remove the countries from `listOfCurrentCountry` only if they exist in `listOfNewCountry`

For this I am using the `removeIf` and `firstOrNull` to check if the `listOfCurrentCountry` is in the `listOfNewCountry`.

```
    val listOfNewCountry = topsProductFilter.items
    val listOfCurrentCountry = selectedCountryItemsStateFlow.value

        listOfCurrentCountry.removeIf { currentCountry ->
            val result = listOfNewCountry.firstOrNull { country ->
                currentCountry.value == country.value
            }

            result == null
        }
```

Just wondering if there is a more kotlin concise way of doing this.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're in the market for [`removeAll`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-list/remove-all.html)

```
val animals = mutableListOf("pigeon", "dog", "mouse", "chupacabra", "cat")
val cartoonAnimals = listOf("cat", "mouse")
animals.removeAll(cartoonAnimals)
println(animals)

>> [pigeon, dog, chupacabra]
```

Comment: You can also do `animals -= cartoonAnimals`.

Comment: @k314159 oh yeah! Extremely nice

Answer (score 1):

You can make it more concise like this:

```
val listOfNewCountry = mutableListOf("america", "canada")
val listOfCurrentCountry = mutableListOf("america", "europe", "canada")

listOfCurrentCountry.removeIf { listOfNewCountry.contains(it) }
```

Comment: This is a more general solution than `removeAll`/`-`/`-=` (as it could easily use a more complex condition) — but of course it's less concise in this case. You could improve it with `removeIf{ it in listOfNewCountry }`. And to make it perform better with many countries, you could make the new countries a `Set` (which can be checked for inclusion quickly, without having to scan the full list each time).

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new list - a more functional way:

```
val listOfCurrentCountry  = mutableListOf("Iceland", "Norway", "Sweden", "Finland", "Denmark")
val listOfNewCountry  = listOf("Iceland", "Denmark")
val resultList = listOfCurrentCountry - listOfNewCountry

println(resultList)  // [Norway, Sweden, Finland]
```